# Issue with connectionString. Using Visual studio 2013 pro. trying to connect to employee DB on SQL Server 2012,

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, connection-string

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 express. There is a database called employee which I would like to save data from a WPF form to a table called [dbo].[EVUSERS]. It is stored in my local Database. From some examples I see that "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS" Is this correct? Or should I specify the table aswell? using localhost as the server doesn't work either. 
I get an error saying "the server was not found or was not accessible." 
Do I have to configure the server in some way to receive connections? 
Here is my attempt.

```
 void saveData()
        {
            try
            {
                var firstName = fNameTextbox.Text;
            var lastName = LNameTextBox.Text;
            var userName = UserName.Text;

            String pass = PasswordTextBox.Password;
            String confirm = ConfirmTextBox.Password;
            int loggedIn = 1;

                //parameterise values
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Employee";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[EVUSERS] (UName, Pass, FName, LName, Attempts, LastLogin, LoggedIn) VALUES (@UName, @Pass, @FName, @LName, @Attempts, @LastLogin, @LoggedIn)";

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", UserName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", pass);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", firstName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", lastName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attempts", attempts);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastLogin", lastLogIn);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedIn", loggedIn);

                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("command number of rows = " + command);
                }

                //connection.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is a screenshot of the server connection.

[image]

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.\SQLExpress is correct. If the database name is correct (although for SQL Express it should be a path to the file, yes?) then you can add ";Integrated Security=SSPI" to the connection string and you'll be OK if you are the user who installed it.

Comment: SQL Server wants to you to login a someone. That integrated Security clause says you're logging in as your Windows Identity. SQL also has it's own set of logins which can be used instead: when installing SQL Server (in the versions above Express) you tell it whether to use Integrated (i.e. windows logins) or Mixed (Windows + SQL's own), and set a password for the 'sa' SQL Login. I've never installed Express so I don't know what it might ask; if your windows login is failing, then maybe you need a use/password specified during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Can Use It For Connect With Sql Server 2012 :

```
var connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;DataBase=Employee;
User Id=(sa or your user id without Parenthesis);
Password=(your password without Parenthesis);";
```